# i just wanted to print a 1-d array like a 2-d array. but when i run this program it is not showing any output

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, infinite-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[20]={7,9,7,8,6,5,3,45,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4};
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        while(i=0)
        {
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                printf("%d",arr[j]);         
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        continue;

        while(i=1)
        {
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {             
                printf("%d",arr[5+j]);        
            }
            printf("\n");       
        }
        continue;

        while(i=2)
        {           
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {          
                printf("%d",arr[10+j]);
            }   
            printf("\n");     
        }
        continue;

        while(i=3)
        {
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {        
                printf("%d",arr[15+j]);
            }
            printf("\n");    
        }   
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, format the code as code and remove the blank lines. As is, this is unreadable.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, look out for `goto`, `continue`, multiple `break` or multiple `return`. These are the usual signs of [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) and as a beginner,  you should always rewrite your program flow if you find yourself in need of them. There are legitimate uses for them, but not for beginners.

Answer (score 6):

Please take some care with formatting your code. It will help us (and you, too) to see more quickly what the code does and what it is supposed to do.

Your reformatted code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[20] =
        { 7, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 45, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        while (i = 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                printf("%d", arr[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        continue;
        while (i = 1) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                printf("%d", arr[5 + j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        continue;
        while (i = 2) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                printf("%d", arr[10 + j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        continue;
        while (i = 3) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                printf("%d", arr[15 + j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        continue;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Three things jump out here:

- You use an assignment as a condition here. This is legal C, but it does not do what you think it does. The code `while (i = 0) ...` assigns zero to `i` and then tests that value. Zero values are false and the `while` loop isn't entered.
- You have confused `while` and `if`. `while` is a loop, but you want a single check here.
- You `continue` after each block. This means that you skip the rest of the loop body and go straight to the update part of the outer loop, `i++`. (In this case, the `continue` is a blessing, because the `while (i = 1)` is an infinite loop.)

Your code shows the ["unrolled-switch anti-pattern"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/03/10290129.aspx): You write four loops with different hard-coded offsets, when the offsets can easily be calculated with the control variable of the outer loop, `i`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[20] =
        { 7, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5, 3, 45, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%4d", arr[5*i + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(I've fixed the limit for `i` to 4. It is true that if you start counting from zero the highest valid row number is 3, not 4, but the less-than already takes care of that. No need to subtract one manually again. I've also added a field width to the `printf` so that the nubers don't run into each other.)

Comment: I love it when people explain why things don't work as was expected, instead of just giving the answer! Great work.

Comment: what if i add if(i==0) instead of while(i=0) in my program.will it work

Comment: @rahul123: If you also throw out the `continue` statement and make the upper loop limit 4, it will work. But it is a bit silly, really. Your code will be long, fixed to four rows and it will suffer from copy-and-paste errors. Compare my example with yours. Programming is about letting the computer do the tedious tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that is a lot of code to do not much - you are doing all the hard work instead of leaving that to the computer. Perhaps you want something like:

```
for (i=0; i < 20; i++) {
   printf("%d", arr[i];
   if (i%5==0) {
       printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: What about `0 % 5`? You need `if (i != 0 && (i + 1) % 5 == 0) {`

Comment: or you get a free blank line at the top :-)

Comment: @AlterMann Or just start iterating from 1 instead of obfuscating your code into oblivion...